# Deactivate css effects when user uses a smaller screen size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I developed a website using Bootstrap, I have some css effects on the links

```
@-webkit-keyframes socialanimation{
    from{opacity: 0.3; height: 40px;}
    to{opacity: 1; height: 50px;}
}

@keyframes socialanimation{
    from{opacity: 0.3; height: 40px;}
    to{opacity: 1; height: 50px;}
}
```

The problem is that when a user is in a smaller screen this effects create a problem.

[image]

Is there any way to deactivate the effects when the user is under a specific screen size?

Comment: Media queries would be the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `@media` queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    @-webkit-keyframes socialanimation{
        from{opacity: 0.3; height: 40px;}
        to{opacity: 1; height: 50px;}
    }

    @keyframes socialanimation{
        from{opacity: 0.3; height: 40px;}
        to{opacity: 1; height: 50px;}
    }
}
```

In this case: 800px and less.

Answer (score 0):

Put a media query below the special effects CSS. e.g.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* override previous css special effects here */
}
```

[See also](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design)